# Java 8 - filter collection using many filters

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I would like to filter out my collection using multiple filters.

Let's assume I have a list of Strings and a function `filter()` to filter out empty Strings.

```
List<String> myList = .......
```

Typically, I would use streams like this:

```
myList.stream()
        .filter(elem -> filterOut(elem))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How to apply multiple filters from a collection (`List` or `Set`) using streams?

```
Set<Predicate> myFilters = .....
```

Comment: you can chain multiple predicates by chaining them with and() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myList.stream()
        .filter(s -> myFilters.stream().allMatch(p -> p.test(s)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you're a fan of Guava:

```
com.google.common.base.Predicate<String> combined = Predicates.and(Iterables.transform(myFilters, p -> p::test));
myList.stream()
        .filter(combined::apply)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Predicate combinedPredicate = myFilters.stream().reduce(Predicate::or).orElse(t -> false);
```